# Cartesian diagram of tensor product of modules

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $M, N$ be $R$-modules. Let $i: M' \to M$ and $j: N' \to N$ be submodules, and consider the diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
M' \otimes N' @>j_{M'}>> M' \otimes N\\
@V i_{N'} V V  @VV i_N V\\
M \otimes N' @>>j_M> M \otimes N.
\end{CD}
Is this diagram Cartesian? I have tried to directly prove that $M' \otimes N'$ satisfies the relevant universal property, but it is hard because one has to consider morphisms into the tensor product.

If this is not true in general, maybe it is true for vector spaces $V, W$? I am trying to describe the intersection
$$ V' \otimes W' \cong^? (V' \otimes W) \cap (V \otimes W') \subset V \otimes W, $$
and it would be extra nice if this worked for arbitrary modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$
(1)
It is not true in general.
For example, let $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $M=N=\mathbb{Z}$, $M'=N'=2\mathbb{Z}$.
Then we have
$$
(2\mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z})\cap (\mathbb{Z}\otimes 2\mathbb{Z})=(2\mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z})
$$
which is not equal to $(2\mathbb{Z})\otimes (2\mathbb{Z})=4\mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z}$.

(2) It is true if $R$ is a field.
Write $M\simeq M'\oplus M''$ and $N\simeq N'\oplus N''$.
Then we have
$$
M\otimes N\simeq (M'\otimes N')\oplus (M''\otimes N')\oplus (M'\otimes N'')\oplus (M''\otimes N''),\\
M'\otimes N\simeq (M'\otimes N')\oplus (M'\otimes N''),\\
M\otimes N'\simeq (M'\otimes N')\oplus (M''\otimes N').
$$
Therefore we have $(M'\otimes N)\cap (M\otimes N') = M'\otimes N'$.

Answer (score 1):

While it is a pullback square in the category **$k$-Mod** for $k$ a field (since every module is free and submodules are complemented by AC), it is not over **$R$-Mod** for general (commutative unital) ring $R$.

For a counterexample, consider the category of abelian groups (so $R=\mathbb{Z}$).  We have obvious inclusions $i\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}$ and $j\colon\mathbb{Z}/2\to\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ and your diagram is the following
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{Z}\otimes (\mathbb{Z}/2) @>{1\otimes j}>> \mathbb{Z}\otimes (\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})\\
@V{i\otimes 1}VV  @VV{i\otimes 1}V\\
\mathbb{Q}\otimes (\mathbb{Z}/2) @>>{1\otimes j}> \mathbb{Q}\otimes(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})
\end{CD}
$$
which is $\mathbb{Z}/2$ in the top-left and $0$ in the top-right and bottom-left, so is not a pullback square (as pullback preserves monomorphisms).